# python dictionary manipulation to make key is the value

Tags: python, mysql-python

I got some values from MySQL in this form

```
({'count(*)': 4739, 'catg': 17}, {'count(*)': 1629, 'catg': 145}, {'count(*)': 2683, 'catg': 8}, {'count(*)': 1526, 'catg': 10})
```

and I am trying to make a dictionary output like this :

```
{17: 4739, 145: 1629, 8: 2683, 10:1526}
```

is that possible ?

Comment: assuming you have a tuple `t` (the tuple of dictionaries): `{x['catg']:x['count(*)'] for x in t}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict` comprehension:

```
{element['catg']: element['count(*)'] for element in data}
```

This iterates over the element `dict`s and for each `dict`, retrieves the values for keys `catg` and `count(*)`, respectively.

**Example:**

```
In [51]: data = ({'count(*)': 4739, 'catg': 17}, {'count(*)': 1629, 'catg': 145}, {'count(*)': 2683, 'catg': 8}, {'count(*)': 1526, 'catg': 10})                                                            

In [52]: {element['catg']: element['count(*)'] for element in data}                                                                                                                                         
Out[52]: {17: 4739, 145: 1629, 8: 2683, 10: 1526}
```